# Web API and Entity Framework user name issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

All,

I have a ASP.NET Web API project that is making a REST call to my service layer in another project. The service project's data access is via Entity Framework 4.3. The connection string in the web.config files is set to use Integrated Security.

What is happening is, the name of the server, "server A", is being passed to the service layer, and failing authentication against SQL Server. There isn't a user account named "server A."

More specifically this is what the architecture looks like

```
jquery file making an api controller via POST to a method within the API controller
API controller method references the service layer DLL, and calls a method within the service class
The service class is calling a method in a repository class that uses DbContext to connect to SQl Server 2008 table.
```

Is there something specific I need to be doing when using the Web API framework in order to pass the correct user name down to EF?

Any help would be appreciated.

Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is double hop impersonation. You can read about it [by this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx).
But i'm not sure that such impersonation is possible via REST. I recommend you use database via special account, not integrated security.